# unable to share certain posts to my Facebook business page

Tags: facebook, social-networking

If I want to share content from some websites onto my Facebook business page, it doesn't always provide the "Share on a Page you Manage" option. In fact the whole Share on Timeline, Share on Friends Timeline, etc. is completely missing.

Example #1, if I go to CNN.com, it is there...
[image]

Example #2, if I go to another site, the "Share on Timeline.." is missing...
[image]

Is it that the specific websites that I am trying to post from are not allow the Share to Timeline options??? If so, Are there any ways to get around this?

Comment: Not sure if this question even comes close to something for stackoverflow

Comment: One is the Share dialog, and the other one the Feed dialog - and they offer different functionality in regard to choosing the share target. But that doesn't mean they "don't allow" you to share their stuff - for example via simple copy&paste of the URL out of the address bar into the page box post in the FB UI it should work just fine ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the share function is programmed. Example #1 seems to use the [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog), Example #2 seems to use the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog).